# Springboot how to validate token on Zuul microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, netflix-zuul

I am new to Springboot and im trying to filter requests through a Zuul API gateway however i get the error below :

> AnonymousAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.aacctt.ms.auth.security.JWTAuthentication

When i put a breakpoint i get a null header/token string value when the request reaches the authentication service from zuul gateway, this happens for protected requests that require an authorization token.

My aim is to be able to verify the token sent by clients so that i can allow the client's request to protected endpoints or reject it.

Im not sure what im doing wrong here is my code:

**Auth Service**

```
@Component
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTAuthorizationFilter.class);

    private static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

    @Value("${jwt.encryption.secret}")
    private String SECRET;

    @Value("${jwt.access.token.expiration.seconds}")
    private long EXPIRATION_TIME_IN_SECONDS;


    public String generateAccessToken(long userId) {
        return JWT.create()
                .withSubject(String.valueOf(userId))
                .withIssuedAt(new Date())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME_IN_SECONDS * 1000))
                .sign(Algorithm.HMAC256(SECRET.getBytes()));
    }



    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String header = httpRequest.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);  // this is null

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
            return;
        }

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(getAuthentication(header));
        chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    }

    private Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {

        final String username;
        try {
            DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""));
            username = jwt.getSubject();
        } catch (JWTVerificationException e) {
            LOG.debug("Invalid JWT", e);
            return null;
        }

        final Long userId;
        try {
            userId = Long.valueOf(username);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            LOG.debug("Invalid JWT. Username is not an user ID");
            return null;
        }

        LOG.debug("Valid JWT. User ID: " + userId);

        return new JWTAuthentication(userId);
    }

}
```

[image]

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JWTAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter;

    public WebSecurityConfig(JWTAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter) {
        this.jwtAuthorizationFilter = jwtAuthorizationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().disable();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterAfter(jwtAuthorizationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(AccountController.PATH_POST_SIGN_UP).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(AccountController.PATH_POST_REFRESH).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(AccountController.PATH_POST_LOGIN).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ;
         http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**JWTAuthentication**

```
public class JWTAuthentication implements Authentication {

    private final long userId;

    public JWTAuthentication(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

    @Override public Object getCredentials() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override public Object getDetails() {
        return null;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    @Override public Long getPrincipal() {
        return userId;
    }

    @Override public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("JWT authentication is always authenticated");
    }

    @Override public String getName() {
        return String.valueOf(userId);
    }
}
```

**SecurityService**

```
@Service
public class SecurityService {

    public long getLoggedUserId() {
        JWTAuthentication authentication = (JWTAuthentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authentication.getUserId();
    }

}
```

**Zuul Gateway**

```
public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizationFilter.class);
    private static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

    Environment environment;

    public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager, Environment environment) {
        super(authManager);
        this.environment = environment;
    }


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String authorizationHeader = req.getHeader(environment.getProperty("authorization.token.header.name"));

        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(environment.getProperty("authorization.token.header.prefix"))) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }  

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req) {

        String token = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        final String username;
        try {
            DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(environment.getProperty("token.secret").getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""));
            username = jwt.getSubject();
        } catch (JWTVerificationException e) {
            LOG.debug("Invalid JWT", e);
            return null;
        }

        final Long userId;
        try {
            userId = Long.valueOf(username);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            LOG.debug("Invalid JWT. Username is not an user ID");
            return null;
        }

        LOG.debug("Valid JWT. User ID: " + userId);

         return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userId, null, new ArrayList<>());

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the sensitive header, `Authorization` is sensitive header by default in Zuul, you just need to override the sensitive headers.

```
zuul:
  sensitive-headers:
  -
```

By setting this property in Zuul gateway application.yml it route request to auth service with the `Authorization` header

Reference only:

> Auth Service reference

JWT based authentication 
https://github.com/nikhilmalavia/SpringBootJWT.git

Comment: the header is still null and i get the error ```org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.aacctt.ms.auth.security.JWTAuthentication```

Comment: Can you share the security configuration setup code?