# Springboot Microservice running behind zuul not setting cookies

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, spring-security, google-authentication, netflix-zuul

I'm fairly new to spring security using Google OAuth2.

What I'm trying to integrate Google Authentication, and by doing so, I'm receiving the token from google and redirecting it to my auth micro-service, registering the user in my db, create a jwt token and set it as cookie.

But my cookie is not getting set.

My Zuul WebSecurityConfiguration is

```
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/user-service/api/v1/sign-in/*").permitAll()
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

My Auth Controller is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/sign-in")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    AuthServiceImpl authService;
    @Autowired
    JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @Autowired
    MapperUtil mapperUtil;
    @RequestMapping("google")
    public UserDetails signIn(@RequestParam(name="code", required = true) String code, @RequestParam(name="state", required = true)  String state,
                              @RequestParam(name="scope", required = true) String scope,
                              HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        // Receive jwt token from google
        String authProviderToken = authService.verifyAuthProviderCode(code);

        // Extracting user details from the token received above
        UserDetails userDetails = mapperUtil.extractUserDetailsFromJwt(authProviderToken.split("\\.")[1]);

        // Creating a jwtToken with userDetails inside it. No sensitive google data is set  in userDetails
        String jwtToken = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        // Creating a cookie and storing the jwt token inside it
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("oauth_cookie", jwtToken);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setComment("This cookie stores the spryly user authentication session");
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);

        response.addCookie(cookie);

        // I can see SET-COOKIE in the list of header names, but I cannot see it anywhere in the browser, as well as there is no cookie being set

        response.getHeaderNames().forEach(System.out::println);

        return userDetails;

    }
}
```

I can see the SET-COOKIE header being in the response, but there's no cookies being stored in the browser, nor there are any header SET-HEADER in the response

My Header response is :

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Mon, 11 May 2020 06:33:16 GMT
Expires 0
Keep-Alive  timeout=60
Pragma  no-cache
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
X-Frame-Options DENY
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
```

Note that I'm still trying it in localhost, and hence my connection is http only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie is the sensitive header in Zuul, Override it.

application.yml

```
zuul:
  sensitive-headers:Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
```

Reference [Override Zuul sensitive header in Springboot property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528225/springboot-how-to-validate-token-on-zuul-microservice/61530068#61530068)